# Use Google App Script to change secondary sort column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I have sheets that have a data range connected to a pivot table. The pivot table has a secondary row sor by the last column. I have queries that update the data range and add a column. I would like to be able to use Google App Script to sort by that new column. I can get the current pivot table and seem to be updating it but the changes do not seem to be happening. I used the method [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/pivot). The original table

I used the method [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/pivot). The original table is as follows:
`

```
{
  "columns":[
    {
      "sortOrder":"ASCENDING",
      "sourceColumnOffset":2
    }
  ],
  "values":[
    {
      "summarizeFunction":"SUM",
      "sourceColumnOffset":4
    }
  ],
  "source":{
    "endColumnIndex":5,
    "startRowIndex":6,
    "endRowIndex":193,
    "sheetId":698433721,
    "startColumnIndex":0
    },
  "rows":[
    {
      "valueBucket":{
        "buckets":[
          {
            "stringValue":"6/26/2019"
          }
        ]
      },
      "showTotals":true,
      "sortOrder":"DESCENDING",
      "sourceColumnOffset":3
    }
  ]
}
```

'
The 'stringValue" contains the text of the header of the current column. I assume that changing that would change the sort column but it has no effect.

When I read the pivot table again after making the change the new data shows up but the UI representation of the pivot table does not change and the sort column does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you replacing the whole pivot table? I think the documentation sets this as a requirement no? To quote >>'Essentially, editing a pivot table requires replacing it with a new one'<<.

Comment: I read the pivot table using the function call, modify one parameter and batch update. I changed the one line of code that modifies the table. I finally noticed that the update drops a "$REF" error on the sheet being updated. I am still lost.

Comment: Is there any file you can share so others can take a deeper look for you?  Minimised and test files are best. Please also do add a sheet or whatever that simply sets out what you expect the result to look like.